# Laravel Image intervention não salva extensão

Tags: php, laravel

O image intervention não salva a extensão da imagem nem no banco, nem na pasta onde fica os arquivos gravados.

mas eu quero ue fique gravado, segue o código pra ver se estou fazendo algo errado.

não queria colocar .jpg no final do nome, mas se não tiver jeito vou fazer assim. 
se alguém conseguir ver oque to vacilando no código, gratidão.

> Laravel 5.5

```
public function store($data)
{
    $originalImage  = $data->file('imagem');

    ///DIRETORIOS PARA AS IMAGENS DOS GAMES
    $thumbnailPath  = public_path().'/imagens/produtos/ps4/thumbnail/';
    $originalPath   = public_path().'/imagens/produtos/ps4/';

    ///NOME QUE VEM NA IMAGEM
    $original_name_img  = $originalImage->getClientOriginalName();

    ///NOVO NOME PARA IMAGEM GRANDE
    $novo_nome_img      = $originalPath.time().'_'.$data['produtos_id'];

    ///NOVO NOME PARA THUMBNAIL
    $novo_nome_img_thumb = $thumbnailPath.time().'_'.$data['produtos_id'];

    ///CRI A NOVA IMAGEM
    $thumbnailImage = Image::make($originalImage)->encode('jpg');

    ///RESIZE IMAGEM GRANDE
    $thumbnailImage->resize(325, 429);
    $thumbnailImage->save($novo_nome_img);

    ///RESIZE IMAGEM PEQUENA
    $thumbnailImage->resize(200,250);
    $thumbnailImage->save($novo_nome_img_thumb);

    $imagemodel= new ImageUpload();

    //SALVAR NO BANCO O NOME DA IMAGEM E A ID DO PRODUTO REFERENTE A IMAGEM
    $imagemodel->imagem         =   time().'_'.$data['produtos_id'];
    $imagemodel->produtos_id    =   $data['produtos_id'];

    return $imagemodel->save();
}
```

Comment: Não salva porque você não passa a extensão... !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário pegar a extensão (`$extension = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();`) e passar para a variável que está construindo o nome da foto e também passar o mesmo nome da foto para ser salvar no banco, exemplo:

```
public function store($data)
{
    $originalImage  = $data->file('imagem');

    ///DIRETORIOS PARA AS IMAGENS DOS GAMES
    $thumbnailPath  = public_path().'/imagens/produtos/ps4/thumbnail/';
    $originalPath   = public_path().'/imagens/produtos/ps4/';

    ///NOME QUE VEM NA IMAGEM
    $original_name_img  = $originalImage->getClientOriginalName();

    //EXTENSÃO DA IMAGEM ENVIADA    
    $original_ext_img  = $originalImage->getClientOriginalExtension();

    ///NOVO NOME PARA IMAGEM GRANDE
    $novo_nome_img      = $originalPath.time()
        .'_'.$data['produtos_id'].'.'.$original_ext_img;

    ///NOVO NOME PARA THUMBNAIL
    $novo_nome_img_thumb = $thumbnailPath.time()
        .'_'.$data['produtos_id'].'.'.$original_ext_img;

    ///CRI A NOVA IMAGEM
    $thumbnailImage = Image::make($originalImage)->encode('jpg');

    ///RESIZE IMAGEM GRANDE
    $thumbnailImage->resize(325, 429);
    $thumbnailImage->save($novo_nome_img);

    ///RESIZE IMAGEM PEQUENA
    $thumbnailImage->resize(200,250);
    $thumbnailImage->save($novo_nome_img_thumb);

    $imagemodel= new ImageUpload();

    //SALVAR NO BANCO O NOME DA IMAGEM E A ID DO PRODUTO REFERENTE A IMAGEM
    $imagemodel->imagem         =   $novo_nome_img;
    $imagemodel->produtos_id    =   $data['produtos_id'];

    return $imagemodel->save();
}
```

**Observação:** *vi que no seu código são salvas duas imagens, mas, no seu banco só a primeira imagem, talvez precise de outro campo para gravar a foto menor*?

<sub>**Referencia:** [Request - Files](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files)</sub>

Comment: Show mano.. vlw.. obrigado!!

Comment: Não precisa não.. o nome dos dois são iguais.. só muda a pasta.. tenho uma pasta thumbnail para elas.

Comment: obrigadão mano! deu certinho.